# Trying to move an image in the x and y field in swift

Tags: swift, animation

I'm trying to animate a wave moving across the screen from left to right, and at the same time i want it to move up and down slightly. Heres the code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, delay: 0,
        options: .Repeat | .Autoreverse, animations: {
            self.wavesImg.center.y += 50
            self.wavesImg.center.x -= self.wavesImg.image!.size.width/7
        }, completion: nil)
```

Currently, it just executes the last animation, so it only moves left to right. How can I make it move up and down as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just apply sin to y to give it a natural wave feel

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, delay: 0,
    options: .Repeat | .Autoreverse, animations: {
        self.wavesImg.center.y += 50 * sin(self.wavesImg.center.x)  
        self.wavesImg.center.x -= self.wavesImg.image!.size.width/7
    }, completion: nil)
```

I am not sure how you want to handle the the value to go in sin, right now I am treating each x value as 1 radian, because the sin function takes in radian,  but you may want to alter that to fit your needs.  (That is, if you want the wave to start at 0 then go up and back down to 0 in when x is 10,  you would do something like sin((x/10) * PI)